# Azure AD Premium P1/P2

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

How is Azure AD determined as P1/P2? As far i can see, P1/P2 licenses are assigned to users in a tenant. so if i assign a P1/P2 license to a single user in Azure AD will the entire tenant become Premium?

The below link talks of different retention periods for Premium tenants. How is it determined
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/reports-monitoring/reference-reports-data-retention#feedback

Answer (score 0):

Everything you need to know can be accessed at [license-users-groups documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/license-users-groups)

> 1. Sign in to the Azure portal using a License administrator account in your Azure AD organization.
> 2. Select Azure Active Directory, and then select Licenses.
>    [image: Liscences view]
> 3. Select the Purchased link to view the Products page and to see the Assigned, Available, and Expiring soon numbers for your license plans.
> 4. Select a plan name to see its licensed users and groups.

As you can see, P1 and P2 are not mutually exclusive, so you can't determine azure ad as the one or the other. Whether you have P2 functionality like PIM access reviews etc or not as a user, is defined by your liscence assignment. You can of course have free/P1 and P2 as any combination, depending on the costs you can manage to cover.

The difference is only at the cost per user: [azure active directory costs, here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/active-directory/)